# How do i ensure dependable nugets within a nuget er restricted to itself and not other nuggets installed in the project?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have this issue with a custom nuget package called core, and other nuget package that reference core to generate another nuget packages let call it a.

My problem with doing this, is that i cannot both have latest version of core nuget, and nuget a, that uses a older version of core. I keep running into version mismatch of the core nuget. The only way i can resolve this is to down grade the core version installed, so that it Matches the version provide by nuget a.

But how does that make sense?
I would have assume that the core nuget dependecies, would have been restricted to only nuget a, but why is the dependable library/nuget in nuget a conflicting with the core nuget installed seperately?